# Paper-tabs ширина по размеру содержимого

Tags: html, css, polymer

Версия Polymer: 1.1.0

Исходник:

```
<body class="fullbleed vertical layout">
    <paper-toolbar>
        <div class="title">CodeStock</div>
        <paper-tabs>
            <paper-tab>Почему мы?</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Еще текст</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Длинный текст!!!</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Контакты</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs> 
    </paper-toolbar>
</body>
```

Что получается:

IE/Edge не отображает переключатели вообще, так как не указана ширина `paper-tabs` или `paper-tab`. Chrome/Firefox/Safari отображают и все работает, но размер переключателя фиксированный ( по умолчанию 100x50).

Чего хочу добиться:

Ширина `paper-tab` должна соответствовать ширине текста внутри + небольшие отступы. То есть, ширина `paper-tab` с надписью 'Длинный текст!!!' должна быть больше, чем в `paper-tab` с надписью `Контакты`. При этом надо, что бы отображалось во всех браузерах корректно.

Вопрос:

Как заставить `paper-tab` быть НЕ фиксированного размера? Что бы ширина `paper-tab` была равна ширине текста внутри него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scrollable](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs#scrollable): If true, tabs are scrollable and the tab width is based on the label width.
Нашел здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197910/variable-width-for-polymer-paper-tabs